# How do I pull a specific commit into a node package?

Tags: git, material-design

I'm building a web app using Google Material. There was a bug in one of the mixins, which has now been fixed, but I don't know how to get it into the package apart from copy & paste.

I'm using @material/button, the latest version, 4.0.0. This is the commit with the fix I need: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/pull/5244/files

It looks like it has been approved, but just not released into a new version yet? An explanation would be appreciated, if not a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to add particular commit(s) on your branch from another one, you should `git cherry-pick`. All you are supposed to do then is get the commit hash of the commit you want to "pick" and use `git cherry-pick <commit hash>`. If you want it just to stay on your local environment, this should be enough. If you want to have this somewhere on a remote repo, you'd use `git push <remote> <branch>` to get that done.

Also, please note that you can use git commands only over a git repo.

Comment: Running `git cherry-pick 1051d76` returns `fatal: bad revision '1051d76'`

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct commit hash and if you are, do you have the `master` branch of the project on your system?

Comment: Hmm I probably don't have the master branch, I just installed it via npm. Would I add it like a normal remote branch?